# Javascript: Making modal popups for all images on a page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement a pop-up modal for all images on a Wordpress page. I don't want to manually assign which image names are going to use the modal popups. I have several hundred pages that already have an image imbedded in them.

Would anyone know how I could get started doing this? Is this possible to do with Javascript alone?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is it necessary to do it from scratch? there must a plugin that takes tare of that automatically

Comment: its wordpress there's a plugin for everything :-)

Comment: That was my first approach but my search was not successful.

Comment: There is a lot of Lightbox like plugins, just search for "Lightbox".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do all the images in a pop-up modal then you can simply use this plugin named: "Easy Fancybox".

Download the plugin here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-fancybox/